# I'm trying to run npm install for a reactjs project from my vs code terminal, but for some reasons it keeps give these error mesages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\PC\Desktop\react-projects\01-birthday-reminder/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\react-projects\01-birthday-reminder\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-23T16_55_34_591Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\PC\Desktop\react-projects\01-birthday-reminder>
```

I tried running the npm clear cache command, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: the npm installer has created a log in your user folder, find out what it says to try get a more detailed information on why it failed

Comment: Can you provide the content of the log file? And just to be sure, can be a trivial question but: Are you in the right directory? Have you initialised the npm project via npm init? Does package.json exists in the root of the directory where you are running the command?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.